# Writing sensor data to files in WearableListenerService

Tags: wear-os

I'm collecting data from sensor and write to files in WearableListenerService.

How do I start the service when the watch boots and keep it running all the time?

It seems that Android wear automatically start this service if there's correct configuration in manifest. If not, do I need to explicitly send an intent from MainActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How do I start the service when the watch boots and keep it running all the time?**

Follow the steps below and hopefully it starts your service from this document: [Android Wear Quickstart](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/service.html)

> Building a Watch Face Service
>
> To create an Android project for your watch face in Android Studio:
>
> 1.) Click File > New Project and follow the steps in the Create New
> Project wizard until you reach the Target Android Devices page.
>
> 2.) Select
> the Wear option, and in the Minimum SDK option list, select the latest
> available (API Nougat) option. Click Next.
>
> 3.) Select Add No Activity and
> click Next in the two following screens.
>
> 4.) Click Finish.
>
> Android Studio
> creates a project with a wear module. For more information, see
> Creating a Project.